# Encrypt / decrypt object in R with library(gpg)

Tags: r, encryption, serialization, gnupg

I have the following data frame which I can encrypt using the library([gpg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpg/index.html)) package and my key.

```
library(gpg)
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c("A", "B", "C"), C=c(T,F,F))
df <- serialize(df, con=NULL, ascii=T)
enc <- gpg_encrypt(df, receiver="my@email.com")

writeBin(enc, "test.df.gpg")
```

Now, in order to restore the data frame, the logical course of things would be to decrypt the file

```
dec <- gpg_decrypt("test.df.gpg") 
df <- unserialize(dec) #throws error !
```

(prompts for the password correctly) and then **unserialize(dec)**. However, it seems that gpg_decrypt() delivers a sequence of plain characters to "dec" from which it is impossible to restore the original data frame.

I can decrypt the file on the linux command line using gpg2 command without problems and then read the decrypted file with readRSD() into R which then restores the original data frame ok.

However, I want to unserialize() "dec" and thus decrypt the file directly into R.

I know there are other solutions such as Hadleys secure package but it doesn't run without problems (described [here](https://www.peteholberton.com/category/r/)) for me either.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? When I run the `gpg_encrypt` line I get an error: "Error: GPGME load pubkey from keyring error: Not found"

Comment: Yes, you need your own gpg key first, otherwise this will not work. You need to replace "me@email.com" with the email or ID of your key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for decrypting raw data has been added to the gpg R package. See https://github.com/jeroen/gpg/issues/5

Encrypted data can be read directly into R working memory without need to store decrypted file on disk.